# Android: even spacing between view aligned vertically

Tags: android, android-layout

My layout have 4 EditText views aligned vertically. but there is empty spacing after the last EditText. I want to align these views evenly so that the spacing b/w, before and after the views is same.
How to achieve this?

--nehatha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using xml, then in all EditText add this tag,

```
android:layoutMargin = "5dip"
```

and in your parent layout (i ll assume its LinearLayout )

```
android:layoutHeight = "wrap_content"
```

**Updated**

adding hard coded values does't harm your code, since "dip" and "dp" are all units which get adapted to different screen resolutions. it has zero affect evn if the screen resolution changes..

chek this.. http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/MultiResolution/index.html

Comment: Hi @ntc, layoutMarginBottom will work for me, but is there any intelligent way to avoid these hard coded dip values and align dynamically based on the screen resolution?

Comment: yes it is working fine for me; but i have to check with devices with different resolutions.

Comment: @ngesh, similar to Venkat's question, is there a way to even out the spacing for different *size* screens (not resolution). I want my elements to expand to fill the space (by increasing the spacing between them) on a large screen, but have at least some minimum spacing on a small screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap every of your `EditText` to a `FrameLayout` with equal layout weight and set the `Gravity` of those frame layouts to center (or `layout_gravity` of `EditText`s).

**Edited:**
Well, my initial solution leaves less space at top and bottom than between the edit texts. But this one works fine: simply add `FrameLayout` between each view and at top and bottom with `layout_weight="1"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ></FrameLayout>
    <EditText
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    ></EditText>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    </FrameLayout>
    <EditText
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    ></EditText>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    </FrameLayout>
    <EditText
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    ></EditText>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    </FrameLayout>
    <EditText
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    ></EditText>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @emazm, can you explain how wrapping my views in FrameLayout will work?